# Angular 6 JSON pipe

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want a well-structured formatted json format. But I get this:
[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is?

**HTML**

```
 <span style="font-weight: 500;">Payload Data: </span>
 <pre><code>{{data.payloadData | json}}</code></pre>
```

**SCSS**

```
pre {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 3px solid #f36d33;
  color: #666;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin-bottom: 1.6em;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: 150;
  color: #e53935;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON.

Currently, it is stringified.

Hence use the below code to get a proper JSON data:-

```
JSON.parse(data.payloadData)
```

Comment: Incorrectly. That json has to do for me. Look at the documentation https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

Comment: That json pipe will make it easier for you to look at the contents of the JSON which is helpful in debugging. If you need to consume the kind of data that you are getting, you need to parse it. Without the pipe the result would be shown as `[object Object]` and with pipe, it would show you the contents. Hope, it helps.

Comment: Ok, can I parse object inside HTML?

Comment: No, I fear not... What do you actually intend to do?

Comment: I use syncfusion for angular, so all the data go through DataMenager, which is at the same time a model to display on a grid. The property payload arrives in a string in one line, so I can not handle it with the type script. I was hoping for a solution that will take a look on that string and turn it into a nice JSON.

Comment: Why can't you access the model inside the `.ts` file. That should not be a problem...